# sass / less files in VS 2019 project folder are not visible

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sass, less, visual-studio-2019

I was wondering how can I add / change styles in an ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2019.

[folder with less files in content folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahg9k.png)

I can see this folder with style files when I inspect the browser, but if I go to project folder itself, there is no such folder. I could add additionally a css file, but I was wondering where is this less folder with all the style content, why it is not displaying in the project explorer?

Thank you, 
darya

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it sounds like you're using a CDN. CDNs won't show up in VS because they are pulled in when the page is loaded.